# Wait for Async Web Service Call to finish inside Task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

So I'm a bit new to Windows Phones and C#, so I know that I'm probably wrong in how this is setup so maybe someone can point me in the right direction. In the mobile app we need to be able to call on a specific service to generate a session guid before proceeding with any calls to other methods, so from what I've read so far it sounds like I need to put that call inside of a Task so then I can use the await method to prevent the next item from being called but what I can't figure out is how within the task to call the web service method and get the results before the task is completed. Here's what I have so far, I've tried a few other things from various sources that didn't work so I decided to strip it back down to my first attempt and then post it here for help.

```
public static async Task<Guid> GetAMSessionGUID()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("setting up client");
    AMClient client = new AMClient();
    Guid session = new Guid();
    client.GetSessionCompleted += delegate(object sender, GetSessionCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        session = e.Result.session_ID;
        Debug.WriteLine("session completed " + session);
    };
    client.GetSessionAsync();
    return session;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about that John, when I was googling for an answer I was getting all kinds of Java and F# answers, and since I needed C# I thought I should make it clear in the beginning. I'll make sure to avoid using tags in titles going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `AMClient` type? How is the `GetSessionAsync()` method declared?

I am guessing, from the nature of your question, that the method is declared like this:

```
public void GetSessionAsync()
```

And that the "async" refers to the fact that the method returns right away, with the `GetSessionCompleted` event being raised when the operation actually completes. If so, then you can use the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` class to help you implement the `async`/`await`-friendly wrapper for your method. For example:

```
public static Task<Guid> GetAMSessionGUIDAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("setting up client");
    AMClient client = new AMClient();
    TaskCompletionSource<Guid> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Guid>();

    client.GetSessionCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("session completed " + session);
        completionSource.SetResult(e.Result.session_ID);
    };
    client.GetSessionAsync();

    return completionSource.Task;
}
```

The method itself doesn't need to be `async`, because it's not actually awaiting on anything itself. Note that I also changed your event subscription to the somewhat more-concise lambda syntax, and renamed the method so that the name ends with the word `Async`, the .NET convention for such methods.

The `TaskCompletionSource<T>` object does two related things: it gives you a place to store the result of the operation; and it gives you a `Task<T>` that represents the operation, and which can be awaited as with any other `Task<T>`.

Thus, with the method implemented as above, you can use it something like this:

```
async Task DoSomeStuff()
{
    // do initial stuff

    Guid sessionGuid = await GetAMSessionGUIDAsync();

    // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you Perter, sorry I wasn't too clear in my initial question. The AMClient is a SOAP WebService that I added to the project using the Add Services option to create all of the classes for the Web Service. I'll try your approach right now and see if it works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should `await` the async methods you call (typically those that end with Async).

So in the method you provided, you should `await client.GetSessionAsync();`

Then you should await the calling of your own method (and idiomatically, you should add the Async suffix to its name too).

Comment: This works only if the `GetSessionAsync()` is itself awaitable, i.e. returns a `Task`. Did you verify that that is indeed the case?

Comment: Nope! A smack on the wrist for me. And maybe another for the library if you can't await the Async ending method (as is, or with ToTask()) :) If you can't await it then your TaskCompletionSource approach is of course the best way!

Comment: For better or worse, the `...Async` naming convention predates TPL, and so of course also `async`/`await`. So one should be prepared to run into a lot of older, legacy APIs that use that convention even though they don't readily fit into the new `async`/`await` pattern. One would hope a newly-published API today would use that convention only for true awaitable APIs, but even that is not assured and, given the older precedent, could even be arguably "fine" (inasmuch as releasing a new asynchronous API not compatible with `async`/`await` could be considered fine, which IMHO is "not so much :) )